# Relating symmetric and nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

The question is as follows, where A is an n by n matrix:

> Show that if A has all real eigenvalues, then A = B + C, where B is symmetric and C is nilpotent.

I have tried thinking about this in terms of the triangulation theorem, but I cannot get this proof started. How do I show this?

Comment: Do you know about the Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: I don't yet :(  later in our course I will though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition).  If $A$ is real with real eigenvalues, then there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ and upper triangular $M$ such that $A = UMU^T$.  Now, take $B = UM_1U^T$ and $C = UM_2U^T$ where
$$
M_1 = \pmatrix{m_{11}\\ & \ddots \\&&m_{nn}}, \quad
M_2 = \pmatrix{0& m_{12} & \cdots & m_{1n}\\
&0 & \ddots & \vdots\\
&&\ddots& m_{(n-1)\,n}\\
&&&0}.
$$